# Redefine a function from an existing by specifying one keyword argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scikit-learn, keyword-argument

I want to create a dictionary with string keys and some existing functions as corresponding values.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
my_useful_funtions_dicts = {'sum': np.sum, 'dot': np.dot}
```

This works great.
But I wanted to use a function from scikit learn and specifying a keyword argument.
For example using `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score(*args, average='weighted')`

I would like to run smtg like this :

```py
from sklearn import metrics
my_dict = {'weighted_roc_auc': metrics.roc_auc_score(*args, average='weighted')}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
my_dict = {'weighted_auc_roc_score': lambda true, pred: metrics.roc_auc_score(true, pred, average="weighted")}
```

Comment: Good job..lambda does it as well+1

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your dictionary to:

```
from sklearn import metrics
my_dict = {'weighted_roc_auc': metrics.roc_auc_score}
```

Once you use above method you can all all the keyword arguments present in the funtion. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html

---

A sample code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize

# You need the labels to binarize
labels = [0, 1, 2, 3]

ytest  = [0,1,2,3,2,2,1,0,1]

# Binarize ytest with shape (n_samples, n_classes)
ytest = label_binarize(ytest, classes=labels)

ypreds = [1,2,1,3,2,2,0,1,1]

# Binarize ypreds with shape (n_samples, n_classes)
ypreds = label_binarize(ypreds, classes=labels)


my_dict['weighted_roc_auc'](ytest, ypreds,average='weighted')  # I am using your dictionary with average='weighted'

#output
0.5952380952380953
```

Comment: Actually, in my context there is framework code that calls multiple functions with similar signature by their name (key strings).
I cannot specify  the keyword argument as you did.
A solution I found is using lambda expression: `{'weighted_auc_roc_score':lambda true, pred: metrics.roc_auc_score(true, pred, average="weighted")}`

Comment: If you run this `my_dict = {'weighted_roc_auc': metrics.roc_auc_score(*args, average='weighted')}` you will get `NameError: name 'args' is not defined`. In case of `np.sum` you were doing `np.sum` not `np.sum()`. If you do this `my_useful_funtions_dicts = {'sum': np.sum(), 'dot': np.dot()}` You will get : `TypeError: _sum_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'`. So you do not call the function.